# Problems on making a Tic Tac Toe Game in Java

Tags: java

I'm making a tic tac toe game and I'm a bit stuck on making it. This is what I have so far:

```
package twodarrays;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class TwoDArrays {

    public static void IniBoard(String [][]TicTable){
        for (String[] TicTable1 : TicTable) {
            for (int c = 0; c<TicTable[0].length; c++) {
                TicTable1[c] = "-";
                System.out.print(TicTable1[c]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    public static void Player1(String Player1, int row1, int col1, String [][]Tictable){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(("-").equals (Tictable[row1][col1])){
        System.out.println("Player 1#, Enter your row: ");
        row1=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Player 1#, Enter your column: ");
        col1=in.nextInt();


        if(!("-").equals(Tictable[row1][col1])){
            System.out.println("Invalid Move. Try agian");
        }
        else Tictable[row1][col1]=Player1; 
        break;
       } 
    }
    public static void Player2(String Player2, int row2, int col2, String [][]Tictable){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(("-").equals (Tictable[row2][col2])){
        System.out.println("Player 2#, Enter your row: ");
        row2=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Player 2#, Enter your column: ");
        col2=in.nextInt();


        if(!("-").equals (Tictable[row2][col2])){
            System.out.println("Invalid Move. Try agian");
        }
        else {
            Tictable[row2][col2]=Player2;
            break;
        }

      }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Gp1="", Gp2="";
        String[][] TicTable = new String [3][3];
        String Player1="X", Player2="O";
        boolean win=false;
        int row1=0, row2=0;
        int col1=0, col2=0;

            while (win==false){
                IniBoard(TicTable);

                Player1(Player1, row1, col1, TicTable);
                Player2(Player2, row2, col2, TicTable);
            }
    }
}
```

I made a method for player 1 and player 2. The first method I made was initializing my board, That part works fine.But my method for Player 1 and Player 2 doesn't work properly. It should replace the dashes("-") with X or O, but it isn't. So I need help with that. Also I don't know how to make my winning part for the program.
If anyone could help, please answer it for me.

Comment: Your question is very vague. You need to give us a specific problem and tell us how to reproduce it using your code.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I made changes to my Question, so people can understand. But I do need some help quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IniBoard is wiping out the players moves. Separate your initialization and your printing into two separate methods:

```
public static void IniBoard(String[][] TicTable)
{
    for(String[] TicTable1 : TicTable)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < TicTable[0].length; c++)
        {
            TicTable1[c] = "-";
        }
    }
}

public static void PrintBoard(String[][] TicTable)
{
    for(String[] TicTable1 : TicTable)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < TicTable[0].length; c++)
        {
            System.out.print(TicTable1[c]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Then change your main to print the board every loop, but only call IniBoard when the game starts.

For the winning part you should check if they have won after each move. Below is my revised main function and an empty GetWinner function.

```
public static String GetWinner(String[][] TicTable)
{
    //your code here:
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String Gp1 = "", Gp2 = "";
    String[][] TicTable = new String[3][3];
    String Player1 = "X", Player2 = "O";
    String winner = null;
    int row1 = 0, row2 = 0;
    int col1 = 0, col2 = 0;

    IniBoard(TicTable);
    while(winner == null)
    {
        PrintBoard(TicTable);
        Player1(Player1, row1, col1, TicTable);
        Player2(Player2, row2, col2, TicTable);
        winner = GetWinner(TicTable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue I see is you are running IniBoard() over and over as long as the game isn't over.

```
while (win==false){
    IniBoard(TicTable); //<---------Move this line above the while   loop.

    Player1(Player1, row1, col1, TicTable);
    Player2(Player2, row2, col2, TicTable);
}
```

like so...

```
IniBoard(TicTable);            
while (win==false){
    Player1(Player1, row1, col1, TicTable);
    Player2(Player2, row2, col2, TicTable);
}
```

Also, inside your player1 and player2 functions, stoping condition for the while loop isn't a great way to check if the users turn should end. What happens if the first move is (0,0)? Then the loop won't execute on the next time it's that players 1 since it'll no longer be set to "-".

```
while(("-").equals (Tictable[row1][col1])){
```